# Favicon works on Desktop browser but not on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, favicon

I'm trying to dynamically display the favicon, I've succesfully made the favicon dynamic on desktop browsers, like this:

```
      <link ng-href="{{faviconLink}}" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="60x60"/>
```

however, on iphone's Safari browser, this does not work, and no favicon shows up:

```
    <link ng-href="{{faviconLink}}" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60"/>
```

does any one know why?

Comment: try http://iconogen.com and put all sizes there, as each Apple device can use different icon size

Comment: It would be worth making your Touch icon 180x180 (instead of 60x60), so any iOS device will find it big enough. It would also be interesting to look at the final HTML and make sure the URL is correct and works.